# Using different environment Variable than HOME for default EMACS directory

Tags: emacs

Can I define an environment variable like EMACSHOME or something, and use that for emacs to locate the default directory?

I plan to sync emacs over multiple systems in use, which have different directory structures. EMACS manual advises having the HOME variable point to the default for emacs settings. But, in my case, it is already defined for other programs to use, and doesn't allow synchronization of settings over different computers (without using git, that is).

Using -25.1

Thanks,

Comment: Here is a link to the most comprehensive Emacs synchronization ideas that I am aware of: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/408/synchronize-packages-between-different-machines  The `user-emacs-directory` is customizable.  There are several variables that contain paths for things I use in Emacs on a daily basis, and most of them have been customized by myself to contain a root directory, which you would probably call your **HOME for default Emacs directory**.  Among the very first few lines of my `init.el`, I have it programmatically figure out which computer and which operating system ..

Comment: Hi lawlist, thanks for pointing to that. I'm thinking of splitting the settings in a settings folder (sitting comfortably in dropbox, etc), and then using the use-package tool to ensure that the packages are always installed as additions are made, combining them with your idea of figuring out which os, etc......